# Return a random integer with a probability progression

Tags: c, random, mathematics

A function `random_int_with_probability` that returns a random number within a range, where the chance to get a bigger value decreases linearly towards the maxima.
In the example below, the chance decreases by 10%, meaning to you will have guaranteed 100% chance to at least get `1`, then have 90% to get `2`, `3` at 80% and so on.
Of course to get an exact number the probability has to be calculated using the rectangular distribution formula (correct me if I am wrong).

As an optimization I would be happy to actually use a mathematical expression instead of the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random_int (int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    return minValue + (int)rand() % (maxValue - minValue);
}

int random_bool_with_probability (double percentage)
{
    return ((rand() % 100) <= percentage);
}

int random_int_with_probability (int minValue, int maxValue, int progressionIncrement)
{
    int pi = 100;
    double mi = 0;
 
    for(mi = minValue; mi <= maxValue; mi++)
    {
        int p = random_bool_with_probability(pi);
 
        if(p == 0)
            break;
 
        pi -= progressionIncrement;
    }
 
    return random_int(minValue, mi);
}

/* Test */
int main (void)
{
    int counter = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    while(counter < INT_MAX-1)
    {
        int stat = random_int_with_probability(1, 10, 10);

        counter++;

        if(stat >= 9)
            break;
    }

    printf("You pulled out the maximum value of 9 at attempt %i\n", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am I wrong to think that random_int_with_probability(1, 10, 10) is just uniform probability?

Comment: @slepic In this case, it appears so, but I am not an expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code doesn't match description

The explanation corresponds to a *uniform distribution* (except that the last value may have lower likelihood (if `pi` reaches or crosses zero) or higher likelihood (if `pi` never reaches zero)).  But that's not the distribution we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void)
{
    const size_t max = 10;
    size_t counter[max];

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    memset(counter, 0, sizeof counter);
    for (int i = 0;  i < 1000000;  ++i) {
        ++counter[random_int_with_probability(1, (int)max, 100/(int)max)];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < max;  ++i) {
        printf("%2zu: %zu\n", i, counter[i]);
    }
}
```

```
 0: 0
 1: 355444
 2: 264735
 3: 178902
 4: 107455
 5: 56304
 6: 25059
 7: 9051
 8: 2500
 9: 493
```

If you can clearly express the probability density function that's required, then we should be able to generate a single random number and algorithmically transform that into the output range, with no loops or extra randomness.

---

## Pedantry around random numbers

The `rand()` function generates numbers uniformly distributed in [0, `RAND_MAX`].  If we simply reduce to a range of size `n` using `%`, we'll get a slightly skewed distribution unless `n` is a factor of `RAND_MAX + 1`.  Normal practice is to generate a new random number if the first attempt yields a number less than `RAND_MAX % n + 1`, so that we still have uniform distribution.  This effect becomes more significant as `n` gets larger.

---

## Compiler warnings

Compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion  -Wstrict-prototypes -fanalyzer` reveals that

- `mi` should probably be an integer
- We need to include `<limits.h>`

Comment: Style: I find it interesting folks who code C++ well using `++counter[...]` and not `counter[...]++` in C..  Perhaps it should have been called ++C? 

Comment: ++C is the language for those who care a lot about performance.

Answer (score 3):

OP has not posted a review goal.  Perhaps add a clear goal.

Below are some observations.

---

**Off by 1**

`random_int(1, 10)` generates one of 9 values.  Given `maxValue, minValue`, I'd expect 10.  If `maxValue` was meant to be the *maximum possible value plus 1*, use another name.
`(int)` not needed - no need to cast an `int` to an `int`.

```
int random_int (int minValue, int maxValue) {
  // return minValue + (int)rand() % (maxValue - minValue);
  return minValue + rand() % (maxValue - minValue + 1);
}
```

Code still has problems when `maxValue - minValue >= RAND_MAX`. `RAND_MAX` may be as small as 32767.  Solution not shown.

**`()`**

Outside `()` not needed.  `()` around `rand() % 100` not needed either, but reasonable to leave those.

```
// return ((rand() % 100) <= percentage);
return (rand() % 100) <= percentage;
```

**Why `double`?**

Only integer objects needed.

```
int pi = 100;
...
  int p = random_bool_with_probability(pi);

// int random_bool_with_probability (double percentage)
int random_bool_with_probability (int percentage)
```

If code really wants a `double`, then `return ((rand() % 100) <= percentage);` needs rework to properly handle calls like `random_bool_with_probability(100.0/3.0)`.

**Random `bool`?**

`random_bool_with_probability()` returns an `int`.  Given the name, `bool` makes more sense.

```
// int random_bool_with_probability (double percentage)
bool random_bool_with_probability (double percentage)
```